# Xcode, iPad 5 generation simulator, tab click on textfields

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, keyboard, ios-simulator

I've faced up with a weird problem with my app (seems like it's a reason why I can't pass Apple's review), 
prerequisites:

- UIViewController with 2 UITextfield,
- No constraints (it's same with constraints),
- iPad 5 generation simulator (iPhone sim is ok!),
- hardware keyboard (Simulator ~> Hardware ~> Keyboard ~> Connect Hardware Keyboard.

How to reproduce:

1. launch the app on the simulator,
2. tap on the first textfield,
3. press tab on your Mac's keyboard.

Result:

NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x60000048b9f0 h=--& v=--& UIKeyboardAssistantBar:0x7ff04dc13ae0.height == 0...

Video: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ag1dw2llnm9sxf/screencast%202018-03-16%2008-59-32.mp4?dl=0

Output: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oeidkmvzhe6n46s/screencast%202018-03-16%2008-59-32.txt?dl=0

Test project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/czqy8zhh8pbr8zo/TestVirtualKeyboard.zip?dl=0

PS: I've found some related issues (unresolved):
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/209609#209609
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/157784#157784

Answer (score 0):

The solution is here: [_UIButtonBarStackView: breaking constraint when becomeFirstResponder sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46566188/uibuttonbarstackview-breaking-constraint-when-becomefirstresponder-sent/46942665#46942665)

For each UItextField:

```
inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = []
inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = []
```